# Evaluate a Dirichlet series related to the ring of Gaussian integers

Tags: sequences-and-series, analytic-number-theory

For any positive integer $n$, let $S_n$ denote the number of solutions to the equation $x^2+y^2=n$, where $(x,y)\in\mathbb{N}^2$.

How to evaluate $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nS_n}{n}$ ?

Note that the sum can be written as $\displaystyle\sum_{x=1}^\infty\sum_{y=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{x+y}}{x^2+y^2}$.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Are you sure about the *can be written* part? The double series is not absolutely convergent, hence by rearranging its terms you can get pretty anything, according to the Riemann series theorem.

Answer (score 4):

The ring of Gaussian integers $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is an Euclidean domain, hence a UFD. It follows that
$$ r_2(n) = \left|\{(a,b)\in\mathbb{Z}^2:a^2+b^2=n\}\right| $$
is a multiple of a multiplicative function:
$$ r_2(n) = 4\left(\chi_4*1\right)(n) = 4\sum_{d\mid n}\chi_4(d) $$
where $\chi_4(d)$ equals $1$ iff $d\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, $-1$ iff $d\equiv 3\pmod{4}$ and zero otherwise.
If $n\in\mathbb{N}^+$ is not a square we have $S_n=(\chi_4*1)(n)$, if $n$ is a square we have $S_n=(\chi_4*1)(n)+1$.
By Gauss circle problem the average value of $S_n$ is $\frac{\pi}{4}$; the series $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n S_n}{n}$ is conditionally convergent and
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n S_n}{n} = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n (\chi_4*1)(n)}{n}+\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n^2}}{n^2} = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n (\chi_4*1)(n)}{n}-\frac{\pi^2}{12}. $$
For any $s>1$ we have
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n (\chi_4*1)(n)}{n^s}=-\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(\chi_4*1)(n)}{n^s}+2\sum_{\substack{n\geq 1\\n\text{ even}}}\frac{(\chi_4*1)(n)}{n^s}=\left(-1+\frac{2}{2^s}\right)\zeta(s)L(\chi_4,s) $$
and the limit of the RHS as $s\to 1^+$ is $-\frac{\pi}{4}\log 2$. It follows that
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n S_n}{n}=-\frac{\pi}{4}\log(2)-\frac{\pi^2}{12}$$
but one *is not* allowed to rearrange $\sum_{x\geq 1}\sum_{y\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{x+y}}{x^2+y^2}$ into $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^n S_n}{n}$ due to the lack of absolute convergence of the double series. On the other hand

$$ \sum_{x\geq 1}\sum_{y\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{x+y}}{x^2+y^2} = \sum_{x\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^x\left(-1+\frac{\pi x}{\sinh(\pi x)}\right)}{2x^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{24}+\frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{x\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^x}{x\sinh(\pi x)}=\frac{\pi^2}{12}-\frac{\pi}{4}\log(2) $$
can be proved through the Poisson summation formula.

Comment: What fact are you using when you say "is a multiple of a multiplicative function?"

Comment: @MCT: $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ has four invertible elements and $(\chi_4*1)(n)$ is the involved multiplicative function. The identity $n=a^2+b^2=(a+ib)(a-ib)$ gives that $r_2(n)$ only depends on the number of ways for writing $n$ as $z\cdot\overline{z}$ in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, which on its turn depends on how integer primes factor over $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

Comment: I am aware of the fact that you may write it as such in this case, but it sounded like you were saying something more general, since you preceded this sentence with mentioning that $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ was a UFD (i.e. "it follows that"). Is there a more general fact you are appealing to here?

Comment: @MCT: something similar holds in any quadratic extension of $\mathbb{Z}$ which is a UFD, indeed, like $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ (the ring of Eisenstein integers). So the question can be solved in explicit terms also if the quadratic form $x^2+y^2$ is replaced by $x^2+xy+y^2$, for instance. In this case the representation function is given by $6(\chi_3*1)$ since we have six units and an integer prime splits in $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ iff it is a prime of the form $3k+1$.

Comment: Great. This now gets into the more classical theory of quadratic forms. Also I guess you want your quadratic extension to be imaginary or else you have too many units.

Comment: @MCT: of course, I should have said *imaginary* quadratic extension.

Comment: Have you tried to calculate the series numerically? Convergence isn't breathtaking, but it's clearly a *positive* value. I think you made a mistake, it should be " if $n$ is a square we have $S_n=(\chi_4*1)(n)-1$", so both sums are equal, indeed, as the OP claimed.

Comment: @ProfessorVector: that depends on $0\in\mathbb{N}$ or not. I assumed it, but probably the OP meant that $S_n$ is given by the number of solutions of $x^2+y^2=n$ with $x,y\in\mathbb{N}^+$. In such a case I agree there should be a minus sign and the outcome is the last one.

Comment: I think the fact that the double sum starts with $x=y=1$ clearly indicates what the OP intended.

Answer (score 2):

The identity $(k+l)^2+(k-l)^2=2\,(k^2+l^2)$ seems to show a one-to-one correspondence between representations of $n$ and $2n$ as a sum of two squares, so we would have $S_{2n}=S_n$, but... it's not *that* simple: if $k=l$, $(2k)^2+0^2$ on the LHS is not a valid representation, while on the other hand, the valid $k^2+k^2$ on the LHS corresponds to the invalid $2(k^2+0^2)$ on the RHS. As a consequence, we have $S_{2n}=S_n+1$ for $n=k^2$, and $S_{2n}=S_n-1$
 for $n=2k^2$. But if we define $$S'_n=\begin{cases}
S_n,  & \text{if $n$ is not a square} \\
S_n+1, & \text{if $n$ is a square}
\end{cases}$$ we'll have $S'_{2n}=S'_n$ for all $n$, and obviously,
$$\sum^\infty_{n=1}\,(-1)^n\,\frac{S_n}n=\sum^\infty_{n=1}\,(-1)^n\,\frac{S'_n}n+\sum^\infty_{k=1}\,(-1)^{k-1}\frac1{k^2}=\sum^\infty_{n=1}\,(-1)^n\,\frac{S'_n}n+\frac{\pi^2}{12}$$

Then, we can evaluate partial sums of the series on the RHS:
$$\sum^{2N}_{n=1}\,(-1)^n\,\frac{S'_n}n=2\,\sum^N_{n=1}\,\frac{S'_{2n}}{2n}-\sum^{2N}_{n=1}\,\frac{S'_n}n=-\sum^{2N}_{n=N+1}\,\frac{S'_n}n$$
Since we're interested in the limit $N\to\infty$, we need  the $S'_n$ only for large $n$. The sequence itself doesn't have nice asymptotics, but
$$T_n=\sum^n_{k=1}S'_k$$ does: there's the well-known result
$$\sum^n_{k=1}S_k=\frac{\pi}4n+O(\sqrt{n}).$$  It's easy to understand it intuitively: it's the number of all pairs $(k,l)$ with  $k^2+l^2\le n$, i.e. the number of integer points in a quarter of a disc with radius $\sqrt{n}$, and area $\dfrac{\pi}4\,n$.
Of course, this implies $$T_n=\frac{\pi}4n+r_n\tag1$$ with $$r_n=O(\sqrt{n}),$$ because $S_n$ and $S'_n$ differ by $1$ only for square $n$. 
Thus, we can write
\begin{align}
\sum^{2N}_{n=N+1}\,\frac{S'_n}n&=\sum^{2N}_{n=N+1}\,\frac{T_n-T_{n-1}}n=\sum^{2N}_{n=N+1}\,\frac{T_n}n-\sum^{2N}_{n=N+1}\,\frac{T_{n-1}}n=\sum^{2N}_{n=N+1}\,\frac{T_n}n-\sum^{2N-1}_{n=N}\,\frac{T_n}{n+1}\\
&=\sum^{2N}_{n=N+1}\,\frac{T_n}{n(n+1)}+\frac{T_{2N}}{2N+1}-\frac{T_{N}}{N+1}
\end{align}
But $\dfrac{T_n}n$ converges due to (1), so $\dfrac{T_{2N}}{2N+1}-\dfrac{T_{N}}{N+1}\to0$ as $N\to\infty$. $\displaystyle\sum^\infty_{n=1}\,\frac{r_n}{n(n+1)}$ converges, so $\displaystyle\sum^{2N}_{n=N+1}\,\frac{r_n}{n(n+1)}\to0$ as $N\to\infty$. $$\sum^{2N}_{n=N+1}\,\frac{\frac{\pi}4\,n}{n(n+1)}=\frac{\pi}4\,\sum^{2N}_{n=N+1}\,\frac1{n+1}=\frac{\pi}4\,(H_{2N+1}-H_{N+1})\to\frac{\pi}4\,\ln 2$$ as $N\to\infty$, so we see that the infinite series converges, indeed, and
$$\sum^\infty_{n=1}\,(-1)^n\,\frac{S'_n}n=-\frac{\pi}4\,\ln 2.$$ This means
$$\sum^\infty_{n=1}\,(-1)^n\,\frac{S_n}n=\frac{\pi^2}{12}-\frac{\pi}4\,\ln 2=0.2780705108482126856110353587636091\ldots,$$ and that's in rather good agreement with numerical results: the sum over all $n<100000000$ is about $0.27807045832349575$.